# Transformar string em array Shell Script

Tags: shell-script

Estou tentando fazer um script para backup da minha base de dados.

Mas queria não precisar fornecer o nome das bases quando for executar o script, mas salvar cada base em um arquivo diferente.

O meu script está assim:

```
#!/bin/bash

BASES= mysql -u *** -p"***" -B -N -e "SHOW DATABASES"    
IFS='\n ' read -r -a array <<< "$BASES"    
echo $BASES
echo $IFS
```

Na primeira linha estou listando as bases e salvando na variável `BASES`.
A segunda linha, tentei quebrar a variável em um array separando pela quebra de linha mas não deu certo.

A saída de `BASES` é assim:

```
base1
base2
base3
.
.
.
```

Como transformar essa saída em um array?

Comment: Olá Amanda, vê se isto ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130280/split-string-into-array-shellscript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/split-string-into-an-array-in-bash

Comment: Eu já tinha tentado a resposta destes links mas não deu certo. O meu problema é saber qual delimitador usar. Já que a minha saída não tem vírgula ou ponto ou nada do tipo, tentei usar \n e não deu certo.

Comment: Acho que pode ser isto sendo assim: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771965/split-bash-string-by-newline-characters ou http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash tens aqui muitas boas respostas

Comment: Não está faltando um tick \` (ou deixar o comando dentro da expansão `$( cmd )`) na declaração da variável `$BASES`? Pelo que vejo, `$BASES` deveria estar vazia

Answer (score 1):

Faz assim:

```
ARRAY=()

while read line
do
   [[ "$line" != '' ]] && ARRAY+=("$line")
done <<< "$BASES"
```

Para conferir o array:

```
for x in "${ARRAY[@]}"
do
   echo "$x"
done
```